# Create directory with script user as owner

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I'm on a shared host (with safe mode on) and I'm having trouble creating directories that PHP can actually write to. Let's say my account is called `matty` and the apache account is called `web`.

When I upload scripts using FTP they are owned by `matty`, and they also run under the user `matty`. But for some reason if I use `mkdir` or `file_put_contents` to create a new directory or file, it's owned by user `web`. Safe mode stops my scripts from adding files to the new directory because the UIDs do not match. The entire existence of the `web` account makes no sense to me as all of my scripts run under my own username, and it only comes up when scripts create their own files/dirs.

I've tried using `chown('directory', 'matty')` straight after creation but get the error message 'Not owner in...'. I just need to create files and directories under the username of the currently executing script, or some hard-coded username.

Answer (score 2):

You need to chown your upload directory to `web` using FTP client or shell.
And from now on PHP will be able to write into this directory.

That's the only way (save from turning safe mode off) as the very purpose of this PHP directive is to prevent whatever activity on other user's files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible on this host. I only have FTP access and the username/group fields are grayed out so chown must be disabled. I think I might write have to write a wrapper that creates files using FTP, as files created manually via FTP work fine. My host will never turn off safe mode so I suppose this is the only last resort?

Comment: @Matt "My host will never turn off safe mode" move host NOW, its just not worth the pain to deal with a crap host when there are thousands of good ones.

Comment: It's a tricky situation. We're getting this hosting for free from a huge fast local datacentre. It'd be a shame to lose all of that, but you're right - it's been a royal pain trying to get things running on this host.

Comment: the problem with free, is that you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on shared hosting with no ssh access & limited control via FTP. The application (running as apache) could not create a file in a folder that had been uploaded via FTP (so had a different owner) without the folder's permissions being 777 - which I did NOT want.
I got around it with the following dance steps:

1) via FTP, create a folder & set its permissions (temporarily) to 777

2) Using a PHP script, create a second folder in the first one with permissions set to 755. PHP should have no difficulty writing to this second folder.

3) go back and set the first folder's permission to 755 (via FTP)

ta da - no 777 folders any more, but PHP can write to a folder ok. yay!